# Can't access tickers with dots using yfinance

Tags: python, stock, yfinance, ticker

I cannot access tickers of football clubs that include dots using yfinance (specifically the Tickers function). For example, when looking for BVB.DE, it says "No timezone found, symbol may be delisted". How should I fix this?

Please see my code below. I have seen some answers claiming that removing the dot or including a dash instead should work, but it does not.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

etiquetas = yf.Tickers('MANU JVTSF GSRAY-IS')
ticker_club1 = 'MANU' 
ticker_club2 = 'JVTSF'
ticker_club3 = 'GSRAY-IS'

hist = etiquetas.history(start=fecha_entrada, end=fecha_salida)
precios = hist['Open']
pd.DataFrame.tail(precios)

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 20)
print(precios)
```

Comment: I ran your code in my environment and was able to get the data. (yfinance:0.2.4 latest version)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what about the last stock? Did you manage to work with the dash? It seems not to be working for me

Comment: `etiquetas = yf.Tickers('MANU JVTSF GSRAY.IS BVB.DE');hist = etiquetas.history(start=fecha_entrada, end=fecha_salida)` this code hte results

Comment: Thanks again, but it is not working for me... it does not download the data properly, but it works perfectly with tickers that do not have a dot